# Loading Configuration/Properties file in webservice (require data to be persistent in the webservice)

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am creating a webservice.
However i need it to read data from a config/properties file at a particular time in day and use the data got in the same for all transactions which are posted to the webservice.

Issue is - as i understand, a webservice has lifecycle which starts with a request and ends with response, so the local variables would be of no use.

Hence I need to load configuration through some mechanism through which i dont have to keep reading file again and again for each request hence reducing my turn around time for serving the request.

Comment: Can you be more specific on your technology selection so we can provide more relevant information, than just asp.net and web-services?

Comment: Did u try static class variable in webservice or a static class that holds your data to be used in webservice ?

Comment: Why not read config info as part of each service request? Unless the amount of information is huge I can't see this as a performance hit. Secondly if the config file changes, the changes will be available to the service automatically.